# How to set the button's action from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

how can I create reusable view controller (let's call it "reusableVC") acting like UIAlertController. ReusableVC have "ok" button, that will act depending from where resuableVC called. I know about delegates and NotificationCenter. Just wondering can we pass what "ok" button should do when creating reusableVC, like this:

```
reusableVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
   // some code
}))
```

Comment: The action handler in the view controller calls the closure that you pass in.

Comment: You could pass closure to your controller, and then in that controller add target for button (selector will be some @objc function which call passed closure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need one OK button you may use this solution, otherwise, you can still find interest in this pattern.

```
class ReusableVC{
    var onOKPressed: ( () -> () )?

    // Create all your other things and don't forget that you should call onOKPressed() whenever user pushed that OK button
}

class ViewController{

    func setupReusableVC(){

        let reusableVC = ReusableVC()
        reusableVC.onOKPressed = {
            print("ok pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The action handler is just a closure. You can declare it everywhere.

---

In the reusable view controller add a property

```
var customAction : ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?
```

and pass the property as handler

```
reusableVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: customAction))
```

---

In the source view controller create the action

```
let action : ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = { action in 
    // do something
}
```

and pass it in `perform(segue`

Answer (score 0):

## Create a UIViewController Extension to include Alert Functionality

```
extension UIViewController{
    open func hideKeyBoardOnTap(){
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc private func dismissKeyboard(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    open func showAlertWithOK(_ title: String = "Alert!",message: String = "Please take appropriate action"){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler:{ (alertAction) in
            self.okAction()
        })
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    open func showAlertWithOkAndCancel(_ title: String = "Alert!",_ message: String = "Please take appropriate action", _ firstButtonTitle: String = "Ok", _ firstButtonStyle: UIAlertActionStyle = .default, _ secondButtonTitle: String = "Cancel",_ secondButtonStyle: UIAlertActionStyle = .cancel){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: firstButtonTitle, style: firstButtonStyle, handler:{ (alertAction) in
            self.okAction()
        })
        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: secondButtonTitle, style: secondButtonStyle, handler: { (alertAction) in
            self.cancelAction()
        })
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc private func okAction(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc private func cancelAction(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## How to Use

```
func didReceiveError(_ error: CFNetworkErrors) {
    var message = error.message
    self.showAlertWithOK("Error", message: message)
}

func didEndWebserviceCall() {
    self.showAlertWithOK(message: "didEndWebserviceCall")
}
```

## Advantages:

1. You can access alert using self(which is your viewcontroller in this case)
2. Code reusability
3. Clean code.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol TapEventDelegate: protocol {
func buttonTap()
}

class ClassWhereDoYouWantToCatchTheEvent: TapEventDelegate {
func buttonTap() {
print("caught!")
}
 }

class YourViewControllerClass {
weak var tapEventDelegate: TapEventDelegate?
reusableVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
   tapEventDelegate?.buttonTap()
}))
}
```

to bind your class with `YourViewControllerClass` and `ClassWhereDoYouWantToCatchTheEvent` use somewhere at view controller initialization:

```
classWhereDoYouWantToCatchTheEvent.tapEventHandler = yourViewControllerClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom `UIViewController` class and pass the `addAction` `closure` and then you can call that closure on the OK button tap from your `CustomAlertController`.

```
final class CustomAlertController: UIViewController {

    var actionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    lazy var okButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomAlertController.didTapOkButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return button
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        addActionButton()
    }

    private func addActionButton() {
        view.addSubview(okButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            okButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
            okButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -50),
            okButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            okButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
        ])
    }

    public func addAction(title: String, handler: @escaping (() -> Void) {
        okButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        actionHandler = handler
    }

    @objc func didTapOkButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        actionHandler?()
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Then you can present `CustomAlertController` from your `ViewController` class and add action like below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let alertController = CustomAlertController()
        alertController.addAction(title: "OK", handler: { [unowned self] in
            self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
            print("OK button tapped")
        })
        present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
}
```